# how can insert Browser control in MFC windows application?

Tags: mfc, folderbrowserdialog

i want create one simple windows form ,it just contain Editcontrol(textbox),Static Edit(label),Button (Name of Browse)..here i cannot implement browser control(to obtain filepath) in my form...i am using the the below path to create form..
visual studio2008->newproject->visualc++->MFC->MFC Application(under templates)...please help me to find browser control to be add with my form..thanks in advance.

---

i trying to insert a browse button in my windows form ..i make the form through :visual studio->newproject->visual c++->MFC->MFc Application ..
i tried ,to insert browse button ,so i insert through right click in empty dialog box and select Add activex control ,now ATL COMPOSITE CONTROL is created ...so i can run my form with browse button...how can i access the path in another event...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on dialog box(To-Do) ,select Insert ActiveX control->SelectFileClass...now we can access browser control in Form...